# Pivot table not creating with datetimeindex from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, datetimeindex

I'm having trouble creating a pivot table from a dataframe with a datetimeindex as the index. Editing to show complete code

The code in question is

```
unit1 = ["U1", "U1", "U1", "U1", "U1", "U1"]
name1 = ["fn ln", "fn ln2", "fn ln3", "fn ln4", "fn ln5", "fn ln6"]
count1 = [2,4,6,8,10,12]

df = pd.DataFrame( {'Date': pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'),
                    'Unit': unit1,
                    'Name"': name1,
                    'Count': count1})
df2 = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date))
df2['Month'] = df2.index.month

# this line succeeds
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df2.index.month, values='Count')

# this line fails with Series object has no attribute month
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df2.Month.month, values='Count')
```

The internals for the dataframe (_stat_axis) show that the index field is DatetimeIndex. The month column also has the datetimeindex setting but creating the pivot table still gives Series error.

Comment: I think it is bug - only works create temporary column `df['m'] = df.index.month` and `print pd.pivot_table(df, index='m', aggfunc=np.sum)`

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't work. Even adding the values keyword doesn't do the trick. Looks like the only solution is on the actual index.

Comment: If you call column `Month`, then you can use: `pt = pd.pivot_table(df2, index='Month', values='Count')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can add parameter `values` to [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print df
           Unit   Name  Count
2013-01-01   U1  fn ln      2
2013-01-01   U1  fn ln    200
2013-01-01   U2  fn ln     55

print pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index.month, values="Count", aggfunc=np.sum)
1    257
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This works. I was trying to get it as simple as possible to find the error, looks like i made it too simple. (See edited code above).